# Logical volume не монтируется при старте, а после монтирования, любая команда зависает

Tags: linux, boot, mount, fstab, suse

Используется **SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11**.
После одного из критических выключений сервера **id дисков** поменялись.
Я поменял заменил значения на новые в следующих файлах.

```
/boot/grub/menu.lst
/boot/grub/device.map
```

В `/etc/fstab` были указаны `/dev/sda*`, менять не пришлось.

Но осталась **ошибка** при загрузке:

```
mount: special device /dev/u01/u01_lv does not exist
failed
```

**lvdisplay выдаёт следующее:**

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/u01/u01_lv
  VG Name                u01
  LV UUID                JofgN1-bFZD-9VYg-WT49-UJOe-Swdq-aCx7dZ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                40.00 GiB
  Current LE             10240
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

Я его активировал и перемонтировал. Но при попытке создания файл, удаления, открытие текстового файла и т.д. на этом диске, команда виснет.

```
 pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda4  u01  lvm2 a-   40.00g    0
```

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda -T verypermissive
smartctl 5.39 2008-10-24 22:33 [x86_64-suse-linux-gnu] (openSUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-8 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Device: Msft     Virtual Disk     Version: 1.0
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page

Error Counter logging not supported
Device does not support Self Test logging
```

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 75.2 GB, 75161927680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9137 cylinders, total 146800640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xaa571b60

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      208895      103424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          208896    58718207    29254656   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        58718208    62910463     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4        62910464   146800639    41945088   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/u01-u01_lv doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: диск живой? smart смотрел? что `pvs` говорит о физ. томе на котором он расположен логический? как именно «активировал»? в логах на всём пути ничего интересного нет?

Comment: Диск живой.
Активировал командой vgchange -ay
Логический расположен на /dev/sda4.

Comment: гмм... у тебя под капотом там не аппаратный RAID часом? хотя какой-то подозрительно маленький диск... или это какая-то виртуалка? и что в логах? после попытки чтения/записи ошибки не сыпятся? `dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/dev/null bs=1M` отрабатывает нормально?

Comment: Это виртуальная машина. В логах ничего. dd отработал нормально.

Comment: гм... ладно... у меня идеи кончились... раз `dd` отработал, то это скорей всего не аппаратная проблема (или не проблема на хосте)... а раз логи пусты, то вообще хз, что происходит...

Comment: ` LV Status              NOT available` смотрите в первую очередь сюда. посмотрите сообщения в dmesg об этом

Comment: Не нашёл в dmesg  сообщений связанных с ` LV Status NOT available`.